# DB2 - what happens when SQL archive log file reches its maximum value (S9999999.LOG)

Tags: db2, logs, archive

we have DB2 in archive mode.
archive log files are created and deleted from the disk.
What will happen when archive log file reaches its maximum value for the name (S9999999.LOG) will it start to count from the beginning (S0000001.LOG)?

Answer (score 3):

[According to the link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0006085.html?lang=en) that @mustaccio put in the comments:

The database manager resets to S0000000.LOG if:

- A database configuration file is changed to enable rollforward
  recovery
- A database configuration file is changed to disable
  rollforward recovery
- S9999999.LOG has been used.